# Constructor initialization speed

Tags: c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, constructor, move-semantics

I run some tests to validate my preconceived idea about constructors speed but the results were very different from what I expected. Am I doing something wrong? What is that I'm missing? 
I'm using MVS 2015 with no optimizations (but it doesn't matter the results are always equivalent).

```
class Person
{   using ushort = unsigned short;
    string  name_;
    ushort  age_;    
public: 
    explicit Person(const string &name, ushort age) //1
    {   name_ = name;
        age_  = age;
    }        
    explicit Person(const string &name,ushort age) : name_{name},age_{age} //2
    {   
    }        
    explicit Person(string name, ushort age) : name_{ std::move(name) }, age_{ age } //3
    {   
    }
};
```

//1 - Is always faster than the other ctors.

//2 - Is slightly slower than 1 (negligible!!).???

//3 - Takes 50% more time than 1. ???

I run the tests using small strings(8 bytes), 1K, 2K string sizes.. 
I was expecting //2 ctor to be the fastest, and not expecting that //3 took so much time.
A last question is it legal what I'm doing in //3 ctor?

**UPDATE** 
Here's the code I wrote

```
class Person
{
using ushort = unsigned short;
private:
    std::string name_;
    ushort      age_;
public:
    static constexpr size_t nr_ctors = 3;
    static const char * const ctor_signature[nr_ctors];

    enum class CTOR_1
    {   CTOR = 0
    };
    enum class CTOR_2
    {   CTOR = 1
    };
    enum class CTOR_3
    {   CTOR = 2
    };

    explicit Person(const std::string &name, ushort age,CTOR_1) 
    {   name_ = name;
        age_  = age;
    }
    explicit Person(const std::string &name, ushort age, CTOR_2) : name_{name},age_{age}
    {}
    explicit Person(std::string name,ushort age,CTOR_3) : name_{std::move(name)},age_{age}
    {}
};

const char * const Person::ctor_signature[Person::nr_ctors] = {"\nexplicit Person(const std::string &name, ushort age,CTOR_1)",
                                                               "\nexplicit Person(const std::string &name, ushort age, CTOR_2) : name_{name},age_{age}",
                                                               "\nexplicit Person(std::string name,ushort age,CTOR_3) : name_{std::move(name)},age_{age}"};

using mclock        = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using time_p_t      = std::chrono::time_point<mclock>;
using precision_t   = std::chrono::nanoseconds;

#define NR_ITERATIONS   (128 * 1024)

template <typename Ty_>
precision_t time_no_heap(const std::string &name)
{
    time_p_t t_0;
    time_p_t t_1;

    t_0 = mclock::now();
    Person p = Person{name,66,Ty_::CTOR};
    t_1 = mclock::now();

    return t_1 - t_0;
}

template <typename Ty_>
precision_t time_with_heap(const std::string &name)
{
    time_p_t t_0;
    time_p_t t_1;
    Person   *p_person;

    t_0 = mclock::now();
    p_person = new Person{ name,66,Ty_::CTOR };
    t_1 = mclock::now();
    delete p_person;

    return t_1 - t_0;
}

void print_statistics(int iterations, size_t str_size, const precision_t(&stats)[2][Person::nr_ctors])
{
    std::cout << "\nTotal iterations : " 
              << iterations
              << "\nString ize : "
              << str_size
              << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Person::nr_ctors; ++i)
    {   std::cout << Person::ctor_signature[i]
                  << "\n\t Stack (ms) : " 
                  << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>>(stats[0][i]).count()
                  << "\n\t Heap (ms)  : "
                  << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>>(stats[1][i]).count()
                  << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{   
    int         iterations;
    std::string *p_name;

    if (argc != 3 && argc != 1)
    {   std::cout << "USAGE [<iterations>K <string size>]" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else if (argc == 3)
    {   iterations = std::atoi(argv[1]) * 1024;
        p_name = new std::string(std::atoi(argv[2]), 'x');
    }
    else
    {   iterations = NR_ITERATIONS;
        p_name = new std::string{ "Benchmark" };
    }

    precision_t benchmark  [2][Person::nr_ctors]{};

    std::cout << "\nUsing string : " << *p_name << ".\nIterating : " << iterations << " times." << std::endl;

    for (auto i = iterations; --i >= 0; )
    {   //Stack allocation
        benchmark[0][(int)Person::CTOR_1::CTOR] += time_no_heap<Person::CTOR_1>(*p_name);
        benchmark[0][(int)Person::CTOR_2::CTOR] += time_no_heap<Person::CTOR_2>(*p_name);
        benchmark[0][(int)Person::CTOR_3::CTOR] += time_no_heap<Person::CTOR_3>(*p_name);
        //Heap allocation
        benchmark[1][(int)Person::CTOR_1::CTOR] += time_with_heap<Person::CTOR_1>(*p_name);
        benchmark[1][(int)Person::CTOR_2::CTOR] += time_with_heap<Person::CTOR_2>(*p_name);
        benchmark[1][(int)Person::CTOR_3::CTOR] += time_with_heap<Person::CTOR_3>(*p_name);
    }

    print_statistics(iterations,p_name->size(),benchmark);

    delete p_name;

    return 0;
}
```

I was being mistaken by the *debug* version of MVS which presents results completely different and opposite to *release* version even with the same project settings! My mistake..

Comment: Benchmarking with no optimizations is meaningless. Also, what does your benchmark look like? What string are you passing as `name` (does it fit into SBO)?

Comment: hi maybe run it there : http://quick-bench.com/ you"ll see the assembly to know what the program is actually doing. Also you can test with other compiler and optimisation. I did some basic test and i foud result that differ from yours

Answer (score 0):

Benchmarking with no optimizations is meaningless.

What string are you passing as `name`? A very important factor is the length of the string, and whether or not it will trigger SBO (small buffer optimization).

**If the string is short enough, moves won't be any faster than copies.**

Also, what does your benchmark look like? It might be that your benchmarking code is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

I would also expect //2 to be the fastest, lets have a look at what the difference constructors do.

- //1: name_ is default constructed and then copy assigned.
- //2: name_ is copy constructed.
- //3: name is copy constructed and then name_ is move constructed.

The difference between //1 and //2 will grow as default construction becomes more expensive.

//3 is valid since the argument name only lives inside the constructor so we can steal the innards by move constructing name_.

Nicolai Josuttis have a [great talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNRju6_yn3o) from CppCon 2017 on this.

Answer (score 0):

I got some different results when I tried to benchmark your code. 
The benchmark runs on a pool of AWS Machines, compiled with Clang 5.0 C++17 -O3.

```
#include <string>

class Person1
{   using ushort = unsigned short;
    std::string  name_;
    ushort  age_;    
public: 
    explicit Person1(const std::string &name, ushort age) //1
    {   name_ = name;
        age_  = age;
    }  
};

class Person2
{   using ushort = unsigned short;
    std::string  name_;
    ushort  age_;    
public:            
    explicit Person2(const std::string &name,ushort age) : name_{name},age_{age} //2
    {   
    }    
};

class Person3
{   using ushort = unsigned short;
    std::string  name_;
    ushort  age_;    
public:    
    explicit Person3(std::string name, ushort age) : name_{ std::move(name) }, age_{ age } //3
    {   
    }
};


static void CreatePerson1(benchmark::State& state) 
{
   for (auto _ : state) {
       Person1 person("Hello World!!!!!!!!!!!!", 10);
   }
}
BENCHMARK(CreatePerson1);

static void CreatePerson2(benchmark::State& state) 
{
    for (auto _ : state) {
       Person2 person("Hello World!!!!!!!!!!!!", 10);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(CreatePerson2);

static void CreatePerson3(benchmark::State& state) 
{
    for (auto _ : state) {
       Person3 person("Hello World!!!!!!!!!!!!", 10);
    }
}
BENCHMARK(CreatePerson3);
```

1. With a small string (8 bytes) the second constructor was the fastest followed by the third. See result here [Quick C++ Benchmarks](http://quick-bench.com/dS8NKoNn_CuPkj3hIA0efqxylho)
2. With a larger string (20 bytes) the third constructor was the fastest followed by the second. See result here [Quick C++ Benchmarks](http://quick-bench.com/BY0pTOQ2UeI4k8Hxod72ODhsyk4)

Answer (score -1):

You make a copy in the third case. Instead this, try something like this:

```
class Person
{   using ushort = unsigned short;
    string  name_;
    ushort  age_;    
public:     
    explicit Person(string&& name, ushort age) : name_{ std::move(name) }, age_{ age } //3
    {   
    }
    explicit Person(const string &name, ushort age) //1
    {  
        name_ = name;
        age_  = age;
    }        
    explicit Person(const string &name,ushort age) : name_{name},age_{age} //2
    {   
    }  
};
```

R-value usage has to improve the performance.

Or you can create one constructor for aboce r-value and l-value like this:

```
class Person
{   using ushort = unsigned short;
    string  name_;
    ushort  age_;    
public:   
    template<typename T>  
    explicit Person(T&& name, ushort age) : name_{ std::forward<T>(name) }, age_{ age } //3
    {   
    }

};
```

Comment: This is wrong. An user can move a string into `name` even if `name` is not an rvalue reference.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, here is already exists constructor, which accept l-value parameter

Comment: @VittorioRomeo any comments?

Comment: this is still wrong. Taking by value doesn't imply copying, as the caller can move something into the parameter taken by value. Additionally, your perfectly-forwarding version should take `T&&`, not `T`.

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo I fixed forwarding version. I still don't understand what do you mean by `An user can move a string into name even if name is not an rvalue reference.`

Comment: `void foo(std::string); std::string x; foo(std::move(x));` - no copies will happen here

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I do not agree.  You have to create an instance for `name` before call constructor.  If you will call like this `std::string name = "foo"; Person(std::move(foo))` additional variable will be inited before constructor will be called if you don't have an rvalue constructor.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Can you show any references, please, that prove your opinion? ^)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Here I can see, that new instance of the variable was created. But, you right, it's created via move constructor, but still created. So, here will be called two move constructors. But in my cases only one. Am I wrong?

Comment: You need a variable to pass anyway. 2 moves is correct - the point is that there's no copy here.

Comment: @Vittorio Romeo  try with rvalue parameter and you will see, that only one constructor call needed ^)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo  If it's clear for, please take bake you negative vote )

Comment: You say: *"You make a copy in the third case."*. This is wrong.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo  You right,  I had to say _make a new object_, in this case, copying doesn't happen. Sorry. But also, I have to notice, that if we would use another type, instead `std::string`, which doesn't provide move-constructor, we would have copy operation. But in this case, you right.